# windows should not respond for given duration in c# or silverlight

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

example- as i clicked on button , output window should come but it should be like blurred or wait for some time (like something is executing in background).. after some time window should  be in activate mode.

could you help me to achieve this without using thread.sleep method ?

Comment: You want to wait for a constant amount of time or there's an operation running async in the background?

Comment: i need both.. you can consider constant amount of time.

Comment: you might have seen this situation in website also .

Comment: Machinegon, i want all the control should be disable automattically as i clicked on button.

Answer (score 0):

Then, you could use a [stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) , set it for the amount of time you need and then disable all controls of your application(Winform?Silverlight?)

Then you just loop until the stopwatch as finished, or display some kind of Processing label.

```
 While(stopwatch.IsRunning) 
  { 
     //Do nothing 
   }
```

BTW: This is a synchronous operation, if there's something the thread needs to do while user input is on hold you can't use that.

Comment: what would be another way if some operation running async in the background? like though wcf services calling

Comment: What's the version of .NET are you using?

Comment: i think its 4.0/3.5 with VS 2010/2008

Comment: Then you could look at this tutorial here on how to implement this kind of things, http://russelleast.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/using-wcf-async-pattern-with-silverlight-3/

Comment: @VikramGoyal , one more thing. If you don't mind the UI being unresponsive or locked you could also disable all controls before calling the web service then re-enable them when you have a response or timeout.

Comment: no i doesn't mean that the enabling UI or disabling. i mean when i clicked on a button some task(control) is loading ,so at that time our UI should not responded , once task loading is finish , you can do what we want... like asynchronous process. the waiting time  some more task is executing

Comment: like when we sign up a website with some data username , password and click on submit button, at that time information goes to server and we have to wait the server's response. in between windows get hacked or idle or blurred.

Comment: If you want the program "to wait for a response" you just call it normally and it's going to do that all by itself, if you want to display an in-between window while it's waiting you just display it then make the call. Disabling the UI before making the call is just to assure that the user wont click anything while it's loading. However, if you want the UI to still be responsive while it's loading then you go async, that's it

Comment: ok thanks.... i am new to .net and silverlight. could you provide some sample code.  anyways lot of thanks , learnt a lot btween these conversation